# Which is the preferred syntax when using annotation-based dependency injection in Kotlin?

Tags: dependency-injection, kotlin

We're using an existing framework which - among other things - provides dependency injection through annotations. In Java, to inject field value we would do something like this:

```
@Inject private SomeService someService;
```

Since reflection allows to reassign fields that are normally final, this also a valid declaration:

```
@Inject private final SomeService someService = null;
```

To make the declaration even shorter (and also make the fields available in unit test classes, while keeping them a part of semi-private API), you could do it like this:

```
@Inject SomeService someService;
@Inject final SomeService someService;
```

When it comes to Kotlin, we're stuck with this:

```
@Inject private var someService: SomeService? = null
@Inject private lateinit var someService: SomeService
```

- Nullable type approach requires additional null check (or `!!` operator) on every service use, even though we're 100% sure they will never be null - unless something went completely wrong, in which case we have bigger problems.
- `lateinit` approach seems to perform unnecessary checks at runtime (which are, well, highly unlikely to become performance bottlenecks, but still) and is rather verbose.
- Both approaches allow to reassign the variable to another value. We're yet to find a way of replacing `var` with `val` without overriding getter or using a back-up field, which faces the same problem. Ironically, they are both longer than Java declarations in many cases.

So - what is the preferred way of declaring annotated Kotlin fields, which will be injected automatically and we're 100% sure that they will never be null?

While I understand that there are multiple frameworks with Kotlin-friendly syntax solving similar problems (like [Injekt](https://github.com/kohesive/injekt)), I'm asking if there's a nicer way of doing it with what we have.

Comment: Can't you use constructor injection?

Comment: @nhaarman Not in case of circular dependencies. I specifically added the last paragraph to avoid suggestions how to make workarounds - I know that there are other ways of doing this. I simply asked if Kotlin provides a way of using this approach in a _nicer_ way.

Comment: Constructor injection is not a workaround. Field injection is a workaround for when constructor injection is not possible.

Comment: Still, there are valid use cases of field injection, so it would be nice if Kotlin featured pleasant syntax for such situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a third way I use in my projects. But it's a hack.

```
fun <T> uninitialized(): T = null as T

@Inject private val someService: SomeService = uninitialized()
```

When using this approach you can use `val` and Kotlin doesn't add any `null` checks.

I, personally, would like Kotlin to have a legal way to achieve the same behavior, but currently there's none. Some time ago I created [KT-10583](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10583) issue and described how the problem can be solved. But I'm not sure it's going to be solved in the nearest future.

Comment: Still more verbose than Java, but I like it - certainly better than our approaches. I'd like to wait for more answers before accepting though (while I doubt it, maybe there's a less verbose way). I think you could even go with `@Inject private val someService = uinitialized<SomeService>()`, which is more Kotlin-ish.

Comment: This is not guaranteed to keep working: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8135

Comment: @nhaarman Sure, that's why I don't like it. But I hope JB isn't going to deprecated this hack until they come up with some other solution for this and similar problems.